# how to connect layers in a Landing zone GCP with terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, cloud, terraform-provider-gcp, aws-landing-zone

i am new to cloud but not in data engineering, and implementing a landing zone with gcp and terraform.

I successed in putting in work different services of gcp like gcs, biquery, dataflow etc. Also, CICD with gitlab. But i am stuck with the part of network, security, and those layers of prod, dev and test, how to create and connect them , how to put an entry data ?

I watched lots of video on Youtube but they deals most of the time with basics i need an example of full landing zone in github as an exemple to understand A to Z how it was emplemented and adapt it to my own arhitecture.

Do anyone have some useful links or ressources please ?

thanks a lot